# How to create a samba that is writable by me but read only to other users?

Tags: installation, samba

I am trying out linux for the first time. I have ubuntu 13.04 installed and working very well. However the computer I am trying ubuntu on happens to have 2TB of storage that was shared via Windows using samba shares. I set up samba, and have the folders on my NTFS drive shared via Samba but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to give certain users read-only access while granting my user full access. Can anyone give me any help on this?

Comment: @Braiam Migration entails closure; a question is always closed before it is migrated or at the time it is migrated. Questions should only be migrated if we would close them anyway, or at the explicit request of their authors. See "Respecting your own community" in [this article by a network-wide moderator](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) (see also [this post by one of our moderators](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1640/22949)). Also, please note that currently the *only* way to migrate from AU to Unix.SE is to close first, then talk to moderators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba permissions work like this: operation on file needs to be allowed by BOTH samba user permissions and by underlying filesystem permissions

set the permissions of the samba share to be readable by others (`chmod -R o+r`)
then give your user read write permissions in samba and the other user read only access. (it's quite straightforward from the samba config gui)

good luck!